# Sum of $\zeta$-functions

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-zeta

I'm interested in the following limit:
$$ L = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{a_1 = 1}^\infty \sum_{a_2 = 1}^\infty 
\cdots \sum_{a_N = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_1^2 \, a_2 ^3 \cdots a_N^{N+1}}$$
It can be rewritten as 
$$ L = \lim_{N \to \infty} \prod_{n = 2}^{N} \zeta (n).$$ or taking log of both sides
$$ \ln L = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n = 2}^{N} \ln \zeta (n). \tag{1}$$
For a long time I couldn't prove/disprove the convergence of $(1)$. 
First thing to note is that the partial sums are monotonically increasing.
My original idea was to prove the upper bound
$$ n^2 \,(\zeta(n)-1) < C < \infty \,\,, \forall n \geq 2 \tag{2}$$
Then by some Taylor series manipulation the proof would be done.
Question:

$\star$ How could $(2)$ be proven? Mathematica gives that the product $(2)$ should go to zero, but how to prove it mathematically?

$\star$ Or maybe there is a more elegant way to test convergence of $(1)$?

Comment: $1<\zeta(s)<1/(1-2^{1-s})$ for $s>1$, so $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\ln\zeta(n)>-\sum_{n=2}^\infty\ln(1-2^{1-s})$$and it is easy to check for convergence from here.

Comment: You meant: $\ln \zeta(n) < -\ln(1 - 2^{1 - n})$, I think?

Comment: @Raito Oops, you are right. Though it's too late to edit.

Comment: The product definitely does not go to zero. Trivially,$$\prod_{n=2}^N\zeta(n)\ge\zeta(2)$$Since every term in the product is greater than $1$.

Comment: I meant the product of $n^2$ and $\zeta(n)-1$ which I want to bound.

Comment: The product is approximately $2.294856591673313794183\dots$. Nothing was found using an [inverse symbolic calculator](https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/advanced), so I think it's safe to say this doesn't have a known closed form.

Comment: There is no such bound, since $\zeta(s)\sim1+\frac1{s-1}$ IIRC.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt This asymptotic holds in the neighbourhood of $s=1$. For $s\to\infty$, your own answer establishes that $\zeta(s)-1$ grows at most like $2^{-s}$.

Comment: @Wojowu Yup, that's right (just had to verify myself)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative way, notice that for $s \geq 2$ we have

$$ 1
\leq \zeta(s)
\leq 1 + \frac{1}{2^s} + \int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^s}
\leq 1 + \frac{3}{2^s}. $$

So it follows that

$$ \sum_{s=2}^{\infty} \log \zeta(s) \leq \sum_{s=2}^{\infty} \frac{3}{2^s} < \infty $$

and hence the sum converges by the comparison test. Exponentiating shows that the product also converges.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it doesn't use fancy zeta function identities to prove it. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 6):

We have the following relationship between the Riemann zeta and the Dirichlet eta functions:

$$\zeta(s)=\frac{\eta(s)}{1-2^{1-s}}$$

where

$$\eta(s)=1-\frac1{2^s}+\frac1{3^s}-\frac1{4^s}+\dots<1,\quad\Re(s)>0$$

Thus, for $s>1$, we have

$$\zeta(s)<\frac1{1-2^{1-s}}$$

and trivially $1<\zeta(s)$.

For any $1<x<y$, we also have $\ln(x)<\ln(y)$, and so

$$\ln\zeta(n)<-\ln(1-2^{1-n})$$

which converges by the ratio test.

Comment: We have $\frac{1}{2}<\eta(s)<1$ for $s>0$.

Comment: Many typos! x.x luckily they're just typos I think.

Answer (score 2):

Given the [prime zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function) $P(s)=\sum_{p}\frac{1}{p^s}$ we have $$\log\zeta(s)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n}P(ns) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{p}\frac{1}{n p^{ns}} $$
hence
$$ \sum_{s\geq 2}\log\zeta(s) =\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_p \frac{1}{np^n(p^n-1)}$$
and
$$ \prod_{s\geq 2}\zeta(s) = \exp\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_p \frac{1}{np^n(p^n-1)}$$
is clearly convergent.